# Visual Studio 2012 XAML Designer - Cannot add more than one item

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm new to VS 2012, and I have this issue every time I use the **XAML Designer**.

Every time I add an item (e.g. a RadioButton, and Image, a Label) to my window, it deletes the previous one.

As a result, I can have only one item in my window, I know it is absurd, what am I missing?

Here is the xaml of the window

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfViewers="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers;assembly=Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers" xmlns:Toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit;assembly=Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="KinectSetupDev.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="600">
    <Toolkit:KinectSensorChooserUI x:Name="SensorChooserUI" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="40" Margin="277,2,275,328"/>
</Window>
```

Here is the xaml of the window after dragging an image on it (from the Toolbox)

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfViewers="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers;assembly=Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers" xmlns:Toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit;assembly=Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="KinectSetupDev.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="600">
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="86" Margin="77,188,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="111"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: This is not the Winforms designer.  In the XAML designer, a Window can only have a single content item.  You typically use a Grid or StackPanel to group multiple items.  Google "xaml tutorial" to avoid the trial and error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As made clear by @Hans, I was trying to add multiple content items into a Window, in the XAML designer. This is just not possible so i had to:

1) Add a Grid to the Window.

2) Add any item to the grid.

It works, here is a sample code:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfViewers="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers;assembly=Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers" xmlns:Toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit;assembly=Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="KinectSetupDev.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="736" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1012" Margin="2,2,0,0">
       <Image x:Name="Image01" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="240" Margin="136,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320"/>
       <TextBlock x:Name="tbMessages" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Margin="10,606,-664,-426" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="974"/>
       <WpfViewers:KinectColorViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="240" Margin="666,0,-666,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```